# Executing console command on WIndows and streaming realtime output is extremely slow

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I spent days looking for a way of reading the output of a console app in realtime. Every way I came across doing it was almost identical to all others, but somehow didn't seem to work. Whenever I ran the code, my console command would not output any text for several minutes, leading me to assume that it was actually outputting data at the end of it's execution rather than during. However, now I know that there is some kind of bottleneck and I don't believe it's with my code.

It's difficult to hand over a more minimal reproducible example, because I believe it would make it more difficult to comprehend, so please excuse the verbosity. I'm not even sure if this issue can be reproduced at all, since it appears to be a problem with the environment.

I'm running Windows 7 (I know, I'm uncool).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA IDE (which almost out-weighs the uncoolness of running Windows 7).

Here's the output of `java --version`:

> Java 11.0.3 2019-04-16 LTS
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)

To illustrate the problem, I have the following code:

```
public class Main {
  private static Timer timer;
    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    java.lang.String[] commands = {"cmd", "/c", "sfc", "/scannow"};
    ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    pBuilder.redirectErrorStream();

    timer = new Timer();

    try {
      dbg("Starting process...");
      Process p = pBuilder.start();
      dbg("Process started.");

      InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
      final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);

      new Thread(() -> {
        dbg("Thread started.");
        int i = 1;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
          String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
          dbg("Line " + i + " - " + nextLine);

          i++;
        }
        scanner.close();

        dbg("Closing scanner.");
      }).start();

      dbg("Waiting for exit status result...");
      int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
      dbg("exit status: " + exitStatus);
      p.destroy();
    } catch (NullPointerException | InterruptedException | IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static void dbg(String messageToAppend) {
    System.out.println(timer.getTimePassedAsStr(messageToAppend));
  }
}
```

I've made a simple timer class to help me debug the code, since it's taking a lot longer to start running than I'd expect. It works fine, so I won't post the code. However, here is the output of running that I get:

```
[000:00.000] Starting process...
[000:00.149] Process started.
[000:00.150] Input stream created.
[000:00.204] Scanner created.
[000:00.205] Waiting for exit status result...
[000:00.205] Thread started.
[005:51.762] Line 1 - 
[005:51.763] Line 2 - 
[005:51.763] Line 3 - Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
[005:51.763] Line 4 - 
[005:51.763] Line 5 - 
[005:51.764] Line 6 - 
[005:51.764] Line 7 - Beginning verification phase of system scan.
[005:51.764] Line 8 - 
[012:42.484] Line 9 - Verification 100% complete.
[012:42.485] Line 10 - Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
[012:42.486] Line 11 - 
[012:42.486] Line 12 - Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example 
[012:42.487] Line 13 - 
[012:42.487] Line 14 - C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
[012:42.487] Line 15 - 
[012:42.488] Closing scanner.
[012:42.491] exit status: 0
```

Usually, when I run the `sfc /scannow` directly from the console, it starts up almost instantly, but when I run it from within my Java app, there's almost a 6 minute delay before I get any output.

I have also tried executing it through the CMD interpreter like so:

```
java.lang.String[] commands = {"cmd", "/c", "sfc", "/scannow"};
```

But I get the same result. I've also tried running it as a single thread, like so:

```
public static void runSfc() throws IOException {
  timer = new Timer();

  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  String[] commands = {"sfc", "/scannow"};

  dbg("Running command...");
  Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
  BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
  BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

  String s;
  int i = 1;

  dbg("Here is the standard output of the command:");
  while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    dbg("Line " + i + " - " + s);
    i++;
  }

  i = 1;
  dbg("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):");
  while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    dbg("Line " + i + " - " + s);
    i++;
  }
}
```

It appears that each subsequent run, be it single-threaded or multi-threaded, takes either roughly the same amount of time or even longer and inexplicably subsequently shorter again. The latest run stands at 15 minutes before I saw the first line of output in the console window.

The app needs to be run as Administrator, if that makes any difference?

It makes no difference whether I run the code from my IDE, or compile it and run it from the command line.

I have tried reinstalling Java - no difference.

I tried using a version ? instead - no difference.

Curiously, when the scan is unable to run because it's already running elsewhere, it started it's initial output after about 25 seconds (down by over 5 minutes). It's the same situation when run within a thread too.

```
[000:00.000] Running command...
[000:00.203] Here is the standard output of the command:
[000:25.508] Line 1 - 
[000:25.509] Line 2 - 
[000:25.509] Line 3 - Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
[000:25.509] Line 4 - 
[000:25.509] Line 5 - 
[000:25.509] Line 6 - Another servicing or repair operation is currently running.  
[000:25.509] Line 7 - 
[000:25.509] Line 8 - Wait for this to finish and run sfc again.
[000:25.509] Line 9 - 
[000:25.510] Here is the standard error of the command (if any):
[000:25.510] End of execution
```

Question 1: Why is it taking more than 5 minutes for the process to output anything, when running it from the command line yields output almost instantly? Does anyone else on a Window machine experience this?

Question 2: I wanted to receive progress updates as the scan progressed. I've not realised, that since the progress updates are preceded with a \r and don't end with a \n until the process gets to 100%, that I won't see any of update messages until the scan has finished, since it never actually registers as having received a line of output. Obviously, I need to read bytes instead of lines. Does anyone know a way of reading this kind of text (that starts with a \r and doesn't end with a \n until the end of the process) without my having to reinvent the wheel?

EDIT:
Mean average execution time when executing directly via CLI
13m 53s (5 runs)

Mean average execution time when executing via the Java app
12m 32s (5 runs)

So it looks like execution time within the Java app is roughly the same as executing it directly in the console, and that the execution time isn't slow at all. It's just that it takes a good while before the first line of output is displayed.

I can only conclude that this must indeed be a buffer-flushing issue as @Andreas suggested. As it stands, I see no way around the problem.

Comment: *Re. extremely slow:* Don't use `Scanner` for line reading. It is extremely slow. Use `BufferedReader` instead.

Comment: @Andreas regardless of the speed of `Scanner`, it shouldn't be *this* slow

Comment: Allow time for **dlg()** to display results within your thread. Perhaps use [**Thread.sleep()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html).

Comment: This is a guess, but it appears that the `sfc` command detects whether output is to the console or not. When output is to a console, each line of output is flushed immediately, but output is otherwise **buffered**, which means that you output in blocks, as the buffer runs full. If you run directly, I bet it takes about 6 mins before you see "Beginning verification phase" (flush of first full buffer), and it's about 13 mins for the entire process to end (final flush of buffer).

Comment: @Andreas: It took about 10-11 seconds to get that line of output when running it from the command line directly.  You're right, it does take about 13 minutes for the entire process. I think you might be onto something. I need to test this more. I will run it through the app from start to finish and compare the time with running it in the console from start to finish.

Comment: @Andres: I'm not sure that buffering is the problem, as after those first couple of lines, it has a single line that constantly updates until the process is 100% complete. I got the same problem when running it through the Windows CMD too. Surely, running it through CMD, it should have no idea that it's being executed via Java.

Comment: @thefuzzy0ne It's not whether it is executed via Java, it's whether `stdout` is connected to a console, or redirected to a file or pipe. When outputting to a console, the `sfc` command will constantly show updates. When outputting to a file/pipe, it likely won't do that, and it may buffer the output.

Comment: @Andreas: Do you think there's any way of circumventing this behaviour, or somehow trick the program being executed?

Comment: If it has a command-line argument to do so, yeah.

Comment: Is there a way to trick it into thinking it's writing to a console, or actually make it write to a console and then redirect the console output?